# How to use custom directives graphql-modules with apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo, directive, graphql-modules

I need help with custom directives when using graphql-modules library. Have no idea where to place my custom directives so it is combined with overall schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to post answer from Discord community, from user Maapteh.

here it the quote from him

> in our app with old version we had everything in common module. We
> kept that approach partly when using the latest version of modules.
> See some parts of our codebase:
>
> import { ApolloServer, SchemaDirectiveVisitor } from
> 'apollo-server-express';
>
> const schema = AppModule.createSchemaForApollo();
>
> SchemaDirectiveVisitor.visitSchemaDirectives(schema, {
> isMember: IsMemberDirective,
> deprecated: isDeprecated,
> ...SNIP... });
>
> as you can see we create the schema we pass eventually to the apollo
> server (example using apollo). We add our generic directives like so.
> The schema for them is in our common module. Read further...
>
> For common scalars we added a common module. With their schema (so in
> schema directory we also have the directives schemas) and their
> resolver.
>
> const typeDefsArray = loadFilesSync(`${__dirname}/schema/*.graphql`, {
> useRequire: true, }); const typeDefs = mergeTypeDefs(typeDefsArray, { useSchemaDefinition: false });
>
> const resolverFunctions = {
> ImageUrl: ImageUrlType,
> PageSize: PageSizeType,
> Date: DateResolver,
> ...SNIP... };
>
> export const CommonModule = createModule({
> id: 'common',
> typeDefs: typeDefs,
> resolvers: resolverFunctions, });
>
> hope it helps you

https://discord.com/channels/625400653321076807/631489837416841253/832595211166548049